# Cisco ASA 5505 Licensing

Tags: cisco, licensing, cisco-asa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a [Cisco ASA 5505](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/prod_models_comparison.html) firewall which I purchased as part of a [ASA5505-BUN-K9](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1065037) bundle.  I now wish to expand the number of internal hosts supported from 10 to unlimited and add support for more than 3 VLANS.  I assume I can do the former with a [ASA5505-SW-10-UL=](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1274680) license and the latter with a [ASA5505-SEC-PL=](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1094659) license.  Are these licenses compatible?  Does the ASA5505-SEC-PL= license already included unlimited user accounts?  Is there a better / more cost effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [page](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6032/ps6094/ps6120/prod_brochure0900aecd80402e36.html), the ASA5505-SEC-PL license does NOT give you unlimited users.  If you'd purchased the bundled version of the security plus license, it would have included unlimited users.  Did you purchase it from CDW?  How long ago?  They're pretty good about taking stuff back.

I believe that in your case, if CDW won't let you return your current device, that you'll have to purchase both the licenses that you mention to upgrade to "unlimited" users and to get up to 20 VLANs.

Having said that, it's still going to be less expensive than purchasing a 5510, however, your throughput is pretty limited with a maxed out 5505 as this [page](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6120/prod_models_comparison.html) will show you all the models .  You might also want to have a look at the AIP-SSC card for the 5505 which gives you IPS/IDS.

**Edited to add**:  *I'm not a Cisco licensing expert.  This might warrant a call to CDW if that's who your vendor is.*